# Nginx HTTPS traffic not working after El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: nginx, mac-osx, node.js

I'm running an HTTPS server on a Mac Mini. It was previously working fine, but after an upgrade to El Capitan from Mavericks, HTTPS traffic is no longer working.

- HTTP traffic works correctly, both locally and externally
- HTTPS traffic works locally, but not over the network or internet
- Port forwarding is correct on the router (hasn't changed)
- Relevant apps are open in osx firewall

The server runs on nodejs and nginx. I'm not seeing any logged errors. I've tried updating nodejs/nginx/openssl.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "no longer working"? What do you see, what do you expect?

Comment: Trying to load the page times out

Comment: Maybe you should use a server-grade operating system to run a webserver?

Comment: @stuart_gunn I still need some more info. Can you ping, is the port open (try using f.ex `tcptraceroute` or `telnet`), what's the difference between "locally" and "network or internet"?

Comment: The problem seems to be with nginx. Locally (i.e. localhost on the server) I can see nginx pages, but on the network (e.g. 192.168.1.81 or external ip) it just times out. Port is open locally but not across network.

Answer (score 0):

Removing node and re-adding it to the osx firewall seems to have fixed the problem.